# Is it good practice to install OS packages using codedeploy?

Tags: deployment, rubygems, amazon-elb, aws-code-deploy

I am using CodeDeploy for deploying my Rails application to the production. The setup is working well if I will deploy code manually i.e. going to CodeDeploy dashboard and providing commit ID and start the deployment. I am trying to automate this process. When a new instance will be added to Amazon ELB then, CodeDeploy should deploy last successful deployment. When I completed this setup, I was getting this error:

```
[stdout]Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/charusat09/blazer.git' "/home/ec2-user/web-app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/blazer-8d8d6c852e45320db5b464988b7414ae28b41" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (3/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/charusat09/blazer.git' "/home/ec2-user/web-app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/blazer-8d8d6c852e45320db5b464988b7414ae28b41" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/ec2-user/web-app has failed.
[stderr]sh: git: command not found
```

This error was producing because I am using forked gems in my Gemfile file as:

```
gem 'blazer', github: 'charusat09/blazer', branch: 'master'
```

When CodeDeploy was trying to install this gem, it was throwing the above error.

To solve this error, I have installed GIT before executing a `bundle install` in my prepare.sh file as:

```
sudo yum install -y git
bundle install --deployment --without development test
```

And, this setup is working like a charm.

**Question:**

I need help to understand should I install packages like GIT from CodeDeploy? or such installation should happen somewhere else?

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using blue-green deployments of CodeDeploy,

> When a new instance will be added to Amazon ELB

Best practice is to use a pre-baked AMI. While, this may not be possible to use fully pre-baked AMI, you should use an AMI with all dependencies pre-installed and only copy the artifacts that change frequently, which is source code/build artifacts.